# In WordPress how to include JavaScript file onClick Button

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Here is my Code...
I tried with getScript function but not working for me.
How to resolve this?

```
<script>
     jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery("#btn_load_map").click(function () {
            var maps_load = "https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=' . $wpgmp_settings['wpgmp_api_key'] . '&libraries=geometry,places,weather,panoramio,drawing&language=' . $language .' ";
            jQuery.getScript( maps_load, function() {
                 jQuery("#mapp").hide(); jQuery("#show-map").show(); var map1 = jQuery("#map1").maps(' . $map_data_obj . ').data("wmp_maps");});
            })
        });
     });
</script>
```

Comment: Use wp_enqueue_script() function reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

Comment: What are you expecting to happen and what is happening,

Comment: @Dragonthoughts I want to Load maps.ggogle.com maps API when i click on map load button, I never include maps.google js in header or footer because I don't want it always execute on page load, i just want to load maps js when user click on load map button, (Above you can see my code i tried with getScript function but js not loading on click button i got reference error maps is not defined ).

Comment: Please edit your question to include this extra information as many people do not browse all the comments.